# GL(2,3) acting on $X$={{$\pm A$}, {$\pm B$}, {$\pm C$}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am trying to solve this problem.

Let $G$ be $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, C=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, X=\{\{\pm A\}, \{\pm B\}, \{\pm C\}\}$$. Show that conjugation induces an group action by $G$ on $X$.

Since each set in $X$ contains $\pm$, it is enough to check $M \in G$ such that $\det M = 1$.

Write $ M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.
Then $$M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

Then, $$MAM^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} ac+bd & -b^2-a^2 \\ c^2+d^2 & -ac-bd \end{pmatrix}$$ $$MBM^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} ad+bd-ac+bc & a^2-2ab-b^2 \\ 2cd+d^2-c^2 & -bc-bd+ac-ad \end{pmatrix}$$ $$MCM^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} -ad+bd-ac-bc & 2ab-b^2+a^2 \\ -2cd-c^2+d^2 & bc-bd+ac+ad \end{pmatrix}$$

So I can check that the diagonal entries are - each other. But I don't know how to check the off diagonal components are equal in the cases of $MBM^{-1}, MCM^{-1}$ and - in the case of $MAM^{-1}$.

Is there any clever method to check this other than calculating all the elements of $G$?

Comment: You only need to check this for $M$ in a generating set of $G$, such as $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right) \right\}.$

Comment: To me here is what is going on: $P = \langle A,B,C \rangle$ is the quaternion group of order $8$, which is a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $SL(2,3)$. Because $\pm A$, $\pm B$, $\pm C$ are the elements of order $4$ on $P$, what you are basically trying to prove that $P$ is normal in $G$. As Derek notes it would be enough to check for $M$ in a generating set. And since $C = AB$, you only need to check $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't know that information. Where can I find the information of the generators of G?

Comment: @testaccount Thanks!

Comment: @MLe You could search for generators of general (or special) linear group. But with such a small group it is easy to see it directly. Let $G$ be the subgroup they generate. The group generated by the first element is not normal in $G$, so $G$ has more than one Sylow $3$-subgroup and hence 4, and $G$ is not contained in ${\rm SL}(2,3)$, so $G = {\rm GL}(2,3)$.